# Project problem, looking for advice about image processing

Tags: python, image, image-processing, raspberry-pi, video-processing

I'm a senior in high school and this year I have to do a project for my electronic class, I  was hoping to get some advice from people with some experience.
My idea is kind of complicated and has a lot of different sensors but not too crazy, the problem begins with possible image processing. I have a camera who need to check for flashing light and send the video to a screen without the frames of the flashing (like just skipping the frame, so the video is always a frame in delay but the person won't notice it).
The fashing light is supposed to be like in a party or in a video game you get a warning on. The idea is to notice the extreme changing of lighting and to not show it on the screen.
My teacher is afraid that doing image processing might be too complicated and video processing as well... I don't have any knowledge in it, and I have a little background in Python and other languages, do you think it is possible? Can anyone give me an advice or a good video/tutorial to learn from?
Thank you in advance:)

Comment: It would help if you were a bit more specific about your flashing light - is it a flashlight/torch around 100m away that will appear as a tiny dot in your image that is otherwise black? Or is it an 800W photographic studio flash 2m away that will blast your image to full whiteout? What is its duty cycle? Off for 5s then on for 2ms? Or on for 1s then off for 1s?

Comment: It doesn't sound too hard if the difference between *"not flashing"* and *"flashing"* is very large. You could maybe *"learn"* the mean lighting and its variance over the first few seconds of video then, if a frame comes along that exceeds the learned variance, keep re-sending the previous *"acceptable"* frame until the current frame is within limits again.

Comment: browse these tutorials https://docs.opencv.org/master/ I think it's doable and might be achieved in a dozen or so lines of code. **please share a camera picture that shows the flash**

Answer (score 0):

your probleme if quite diificult, cause it envolved unknown environnement in a dynamic time range.

if you admit as an axiom that your camera has for exemple a frame rate of 20 FPS, the chances that your difference between Frame f' and next frame f+1 are quite low.

UNLESS you have a huge color change du to ligth flash,
So you can process with an image similarity such as ssim or psim
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/06/19/image-difference-with-opencv-and-python/

if your image is over a certain treshold that you have to define ( can use also a kalmann filter to dynamically reajust the difference treshold)

so it will probably mean that your flash light is on.